# Are HTML DOM elements injected into a mounted Vue js app's scope by 3rd party Javascript code accessible to Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When creating a Vuejs app we pick an Element (Id etc) to mount the Vue app to:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

Where our HTML code might look like this (using Vue's get started example):

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

The question I haven't been able to answer after some googling (due to search pollution?) is whether or not a Dom object inserted into that scope by a 3rd Party script after initial DOM load, where that element would normally be accessible to our Vue app if it existed in our HTML, would be accessible within our scope, for example:

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="some3rdPartyDivGeneratedAfterDOMLoad">Contents here</div>
    {{ message }}
</div>
```

Between the time I have spent posting this and googling I probably could have mocked this up just as quickly to test it — and my assumption as of now is that PROBABLY Vue is monitoring the DOM as it exists at any given moment (rather than whatever the HTML DOM started out as plus whatever changes the Vue App it's self made.)

I figured this MIGHT save someone some time if for no other reason than the title (of the question) is closer to what I (as a novice / intermediate Vue dev) was googling than apparently whatever doc the answer actually lies in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Elements added in by third parties are direct DOM modifications and are not managed by Vue. They are also not actively destroyed, but if the parent node of inserted stuff is destroyed, the inserted DOM elements are of course also destroyed. Inserted variable markers (e.g. `{{ variable }}`) do nothing, because they are not part of the template. You can still access these inserted nodes through DOM operations, which can be made somewhat easier by using a `ref` on a parent node. That is as far as you will get though.

Overall I recommend against injecting anything into your Vue application. Instead inject it outside the vue application where it makes a lot more sense.

A testscript to see what can be done:

```
<template>
  <div id="comp-child1">
    <div id="part1" v-if="toggled" ref="part1">
      <div id="marker"></div>
      {{ message }}
    </div>
    <div v-else>Something else</div>

    <button @click="toggled = !toggled">Toggle</button>
    <button @click="printNodes">Print nodes under part 1</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "child1",

  data() {
    return {
      message: "",
      intervalRef: null,

      toggled: true
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.intervalRef = window.setInterval(this.changeText, 100);
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.intervalRef) {
      window.clearInterval(this.intervalRef);
    }
  },

  methods: {
    changeText() {
      // Extremely poor randomiser
      this.message = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    },

    printNodes() {
      console.log(this.$refs.part1.childNodes);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

As well as some external DOM manipulation:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>App.vue</p>
    <router-view/>

    <button @click="addSomeDOMElementManually">Add a DOM element</button>
    <button @click="addVariableMarker">Add variable marker</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",

  methods: {
    addSomeDOMElementManually() {
      const afterMarker = document.querySelector("#marker");
      const elem = document.querySelector("#part1");

      const newElement = document.createElement("div");
      newElement.innerHTML = "<b>Hello</b>, world";
      elem.insertBefore(newElement, afterMarker);
    },

    addVariableMarker() {
      const afterMarker = document.querySelector("#marker");
      const elem = document.querySelector("#part1");

      const newElement = document.createElement("div");
      newElement.innerHTML = "{{ message }}";
      elem.insertBefore(newElement, afterMarker);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[image: Edit Experiments with DOM manipulation]